# Convert "datetime" to "MonthName DAY,YEAR"

Tags: t-sql, datetime, format

I have a *datetime* field and what to covert it to "MonthName DAY, YEAR" format.

For example, the following date:

```
2013-01-16 00:00:00.000
```

will be convert to:

```
January 16,2013
```

I am doing this with the following statement:

```
CAST(DATENAME(MONTH,DateTime) AS VARCHAR(12)) + ' ' + CAST(DATEPART(DAY,DateTime) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ','+ CAST(YEAR(DateTime) AS VARCHAR(4))
```

As you can see I am using separate date function for each part of the datetime value and converting it to string in order to concatenate it with the other parts.

Is there a more clear and faster way, using only covert/cast function?

Comment: You should generally try to do this formatting as close to the user as possible - if this is going to pass through other code, I'd recommend leaving it as `datetime` and letting the other code use (usually far better) string formatting facilities.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I can agree that this will give more freedom to the programmer that will handle the result row set from the SQL, but in some cases when the output is strictly defined I prefer to format the data in SQL if possible and (in my case) to use javascript/html just to render it.

Comment: The advice arises from the large number of cases where (somehow) people have decided that the best way to deal with "formatting issues" with datetimes is to convert them to strings (and then, often, convert them back to datetime values later) - without recognizing that the "formatting issues" only arise once they start treating datetime data as strings in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
select 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), dt, 107) AS [Mon DD, YYYY] 
from temp
```

Output:

```
Jan 16, 2013
```

### [Live Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ec47f5/2)

Comment: +1, Thanks, I compare the execution plans from my both yours and my code. Your solution has smaller(twice) cached plan size. The other criteria are the same, but it is definitely more clear.